# Adicionar comentario o uma coluna com entity framework core fluent api

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Como faço para adicionar um comentário a uma coluna. Em sql faço assim:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabela MODIFY COLUMN 'nome' varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Teste' AFTER `nome`;
```

Com faço em entity framework core fluent api?